# i need add the XML data in xsl form to check the condition

Tags: xml, xslt

Field CashFlowAttach contains XML code in database, i need to check the condition whether CashFlowAttach field contains this data `<p xmlns:Utils="cim:Utils"></p>` field should be null using XSL form

```
<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($CashFlowAttach)!=0">
        <xsl:if test="string-length($CashFlowAttach)!='<p xmlns:Utils="cim:Utils"></p>'">
            <a>
               <xsl:attribute name="onclick">ajaxcallingForFileDownload
               ('<xsl:value-of select="$CashFlowAttach" />')  </xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:value-of select="$CashFlowAttach" />
            </a>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Do you have a question to ask us?

Comment: why are you comparing .. `string-length($CashFlowAttach)` with some tag like `<p>`, what is that you want to achieve? you need to explain it at your best to make fellow members understand .. there is no explanation neither the code is understandable .. Please do it at earliest before this question is discouraged with downvotes and close-votes !

Comment: Please edit the content of your question so that it has an **actual question** and a description of what you want to do.

Comment: In line 3 i need to check the condition with XML DATA CONTAIN., whether it is possible or not

Comment: <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="string-length($CashFlowAttach)!=0">
          <xsl:if test="string-length($CashFlowAttach)!='&lt;p xmlns:Utils="cim:Utils"&gt;&lt;/p&gt;'"></xsl:if>
           <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">ajaxcallingForFileDownload('<xsl:value-of select="$CashFlowAttach" />')  </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$CashFlowAttach" />
           </a>
          </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>

Comment: Post your sample XML, hope I can get it..

Comment: If data contains <p xmlns:Utils="cim:Utils"><a href="resources/Attachment/SPlan"><image border="0" width="64px" height="48px" src="resources/Content/images/CIMtrek_SPlan_123.gif"></image></a></p>

Comment: If check the condition for CashFlowAttached need to check the condition <p xmlns:Utils="cim:Utils"></p>

Comment: @user1619558 Please clarify your question by _editing_ the question, not by putting code in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that `$CashFlowAttach` contains text and not actual XML, this test would probably work:

```
<xsl:if test="not(contains($CashFlowAttach, 
                      '&lt;p xmlns:Utils=&quot;cim:Utils&quot;&gt;'))">
```

Note that I have it only checking whether the variable contains the opening tag, if you have it check for that whole portion that you have there, then the test would fail if the `p` has any content in it.

Could you give this a try?

Comment: Quotes problem.. Single quote and double quote problem in that condition

Comment: Thanks, But i need that condition not contains that piece of XML code

Comment: How about now (with a not() around it).

Comment: It seems that your follow-up question is incomplete.

Comment: Yes,Can i post another Question

Comment: Certainly.  If my above answer solved your original question, could you mark it as correct?  Thank you!